# Laravel searching on hasone relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to be able to perform search on values in hasOne relationship.

I have **deliverables** and **deliverable_versions** table with **hasMany** relationship. So a deliverable can have many deliverable_versions.

I also have **deliverable** **hasOne** **deliverable_version** to get the latest version.

I want to be able to list the deliverables, but after performing a search on the latest version.

The problem is, in my current database, the versions have all the information needed in search.

So for example, I want to search on the values on "recent version" like this.

```
$deliverables = $account->deliverables()->with('recentVersion');
$deliverables = $deliverables->search($search); //<--Search on recent version
$deliverables = $deliverables->paginate(4);
```

How can I achieve something like this in Laravel Eloquent?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share the code of search method ??

Comment: The code of the search method is what I am looking to accomplish here.

Comment: I'm not sure with the question
Does deliverable != deliverables?
how do you distinguish the latest version? by created date?

Comment: Yeah, the latest version is just version that was created last. How can I list the deliverables and perform search & pagination by the parameters of its latest version?